# Hierarchical vs Lookup

Tags: user

I'm having confusion over the answers, both seems to be correct at certain point perspective. I'm sorry if this is not the right place to post.

The administrator at UC has been asked to setup an approval process that ensures the hiring manager has approved the salary that HR will be offering the candidate. If the offered salary is over $125,000, the appropriate regional director also needs to approve the salary before HR makes the offer. How can the system be configured to automate the routing of the approval request to the correct regional director?

c) Create a lookup field on the user record to store the name of the appropriate regional director

d) Create a hierarchical relationship field on the user record to store the name of the appropriate regional director

Comment: A lookup from user object to user object is a hierarchical relationship

Answer (score 3):

Correct answer is D

ApprovalProcess does not allow you to select Users that are referenced by object being Approved, but it allows you to select Users related on User object.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a role field on the user record or create a separate object for hiring process. Based on the role you can direct the approval request to correct person.

Comment: but those answers were not available in the test question lol

Comment: well he is having confusion over answers :)